# Redacting SSNs from Logs in dotnet core

Tags: c#, logging, dependency-injection, .net-core

I’m building a dotnet core application and I need to redact social security numbers from logs. Currently, the application is using the console logger. Is there a best practice for this? Essentially, I would like to create an adapter for the console logger that intercepts log message, redacts social security numbers, and sends it on to the console logger. Something like the code below.

```
public class LogRedactor : ILogger
{
    private static readonly Regex SsnRegex = new Regex("<SSN>(.*)</SSN>", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public LogRedactor(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception,
        Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        if (state is FormattedLogValues)
            _logger.Log(logLevel, eventId, state, exception,
                (o, e) => SsnRegex.Replace(o.ToString(), "<SSN>REDACTED</SSN>"));
        else
            _logger.Log(logLevel, eventId, state, exception, formatter);
    }

    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
    {
        return _logger.IsEnabled(logLevel);
    }

    public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
    {
        return _logger.BeginScope(state);
    }
}

public class RedactedConsoleLoggingProvider : ILoggerProvider
{
    private readonly ConsoleLoggerProvider _consoleLogger;

    public RedactedConsoleLoggingProvider(ConsoleLoggerProvider consoleLogger)
    {
        _consoleLogger = consoleLogger;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _consoleLogger.Dispose();
    }

    public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
    {
        var logger = _consoleLogger.CreateLogger(categoryName);
        return new LogRedactor(logger);
    }
}
```

What I have above "works" but I worry that it's brittle and not complete. Any direction is greatly appreciated.